# Define a routed element with multiple templates

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular-template

I'm trying to create a routed component which has multiple template entry points and I don't know if this is possible in Angular. I'll elaborate a little.

In Angular we can create nested elements which contain templateRefs to inject some part of the child component into the parent component (for example, the `Menu from child` in the following image).

[image]

The main problem is that I don't know how I can do this with routed components. I want that the navigation on parent makes the navigation on the ng-content (which now will be a `<router-outlet>`) but also updates the Menu based on some template I define in the child component. Is this possible? How can I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you use child component by using the selector in parent component you can this easily. But since you are using the routed component and are using the `<router-outlet>` for rendering the child component.

You need to pass the data from child component to the parent.
For doing this you can use the **service** having the data to be rendered in the parent component in the section where the data is decided in the child component.

For this you can create one service suppose **data.service.ts**:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DatService {
  dataToRendered$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  constructor(){}
  setDataToRender(data:any){
   this.dataToRender.next(data);
  }
}
```

So in parent component you can use the instance of this service and keep the variable **dataToRender** subscribed. Whenever the data gets changed you would get the updated data.

```
this.dataService.dataToRender.subscribe((data)={ console.log(data)})
```

And in the child component you can just call the method **setDataToRender()** method to update the data in parent component, by using the instance of the **DataService**.
The sample code is as shown:

```
this.dataService.setDataToRender({name:'Demo'});
```

**Edited:**

If you have your template defined in the html of child component. you can get it in .ts using  `@ViewChild('template') template: TemplateRef;`
Your html file of child component should have:

```
<ng-template #template></ng-template>
```

and call setDataToRender(this.template).

In parent component get this data and define `<ng-container #vc></ng-container>` in html. Now Add the following in .ts

```
  @ViewChild('vc', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vc: ViewContainerRef;

  this.dataService.dataToRender.subscribe((data)={ 
   this.vc.insert(data);
   })
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't want data to come from the child component, I want a template that would get rendered in the parent component...

Comment: I have not tried this ever, but you can pass the object of type templateRef and add that in parent component using createEmbeddedView.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hey, I have edited the answer.Please have look into it.